# Is there any method to automatically monitor browser cache and make some change in some cache files?

Tags: javascript, caching, web

I need to build a webpage. There is a link redirecting users to another website. But when users are redirected to the website through my page, I need to monitor users' browser cache and make some changes in some cache files(these files are from the website)
How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The browser's cache cannot be directly accessed or modified by web pages.

Even if it could, you wouldn't be allowed to alter cached files belonging to another web site.